# What is the significance between the below declarations in Swift

Tags: swift, variables

I just stumble on declaration for Int. what is the significance between below declarations.

Declaration 1:

> var minSpeed: Int {
> return 99
> }

Declaration 2:

> var minSpeed = 99

Comment: Try below code: `var t = MyStruct(); print("1.0: \(t.a)"); print("2.0: \(t.b)"); t.a = 100; t.b = 100; print("1.1: \(t.a)"); print("2.1: \(t.b)")` with `struct MyStruct { var a: Int { return 99 }; var b = 99}` What's the compiler error thrown? How do you understand it?

Comment: You can check `Read-Only Computed Properties` https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html that's how they are called to get more infos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is a read-only computed property; you cannot set it directly and the value returned is computed each time the variable is read. For example:

```
var currentDate: Date {
    Date()
}
print(currentDate) // some date
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    print(currentDate) // some slightly later date
}
```

The second is a stored property; you can set it directly to some value, which is already evaluated. For example:

```
var currentDate = Date()
print(currentDate) // some date
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    print(currentDate) // the same date
}
```

You can read about the different kinds of properties in the [Swift docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html).

---

Note that `var currentDate: Date { Date() }` is shorthand for

```
var currentDate: Date {
    get {
        return Date()
    }
}
```

The getter is like a function that is executed whenever you read the variable. You can *think* of this as equivalent to:

```
func getCurrentDate() -> Date {
    return Date()
}
```

Hopefully that makes what is happening clear.

Answer (score 1):

The first declaration is a computed property, the second is a stored property.

As shown in the example/comment by @Larme, the biggest practical difference is that you have implicitly declared only a getter for Declaration 1, so it will be a read-only property.

Declaration 2 will have a default getter and setter "under the hood."